# How to add scroll bar to the Relative Layout?

Tags: android-layout, android

I am new to the Android app development. Now I am designing an app, in that I have an `Activity` which is containing some content but these content is some what more so the content is out of the screen. Now I wanna show that content to the user, but I don't know how to keep scrollers to the `Activity`.

How to show the total content to the end user with the scroller using `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

hi see the following sample code of xml file.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dip"
                android:text="@+id/TextView01" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dip"
                android:text="@+id/TextView01" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dip"
                android:text="@+id/TextView01" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dip"
                android:text="@+id/TextView01" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dip"
                android:text="@+id/TextView01" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dip"
                android:text="@+id/TextView01" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dip"
                android:text="@+id/TextView01" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dip"
                android:text="@+id/TextView01" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dip"
                android:text="@+id/TextView01" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: `RelativeLayout`is excess in this view hierarchy, IMO.

Answer (score 15):

Just put your`RelativeLayout` inside `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  ------- here RelativeLayout ------
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to enclose it with a `scrollView`.

Answer (score 5):

Check the following sample layout file

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/white">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_blank" android:clickable="true" /> </RelativeLayout> </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="638dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    style="@style/normalcode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="Email" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    style="@style/normalcode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:text="Password" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    style="@style/normalcode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:text="Confirm Password" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    style="@style/normalcode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="Date of Birth" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    style="@style/normalcode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:text="Gender" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:text="Male" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Female" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:background="@drawable/rectbutton"
    android:text="Sign Up" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
```

and works perfectly