# android alignParentTop not working in scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

i have scrollview in xml file and i try to insert relative layout in button position .i created layout but i can't insert layout button position
this is a my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainpagespleshscreen" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i have no idea what is  a wrong in my code.if anyone knows solution please help me thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add scroll bar to the Relative Layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850192/how-to-add-scroll-bar-to-the-relative-layout)

Comment: I think the problem is, that Your relative layout which should be on top is inside another relative layout whicht has no attributes for the alignment.

Comment: Why do you want to align top and left inside of a ScrollView? That's the default position.

Answer (score 0):

You could have performance problems because you imbricated many ViewGroup(s). You should make the scrollview as the parent, put **one** RelativeLayout in the ScrollView, and put your elements in this RelativeLayout.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/mainpagespleshscreen" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <requestFocus/>
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Don't forget to use the Design tab at the bottom of the xml editor in Android Studio, it could help you designing RelativeLayouts